# Consolidate a list of members enrolled each month to a range of start and stop dates per member in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have a very tall data frame of all the months each doctor is enrolled:

| doctor | month_enrolled |
| --- | --- |
| Dr. Brown | March, 2021 |
| Dr. Brown | April, 2021 |
| Dr. Brown | July, 2021 |
| Dr. Brown | August, 2021 |
| Dr. Green | April, 2021 |
| Dr. Green | May, 2021 |
| Dr. Black | Jan, 2021 |
| Dr. Black | May, 2021 |
| Dr. Black | June, 2021 |
| Dr. Black | July, 2021 |
| Dr. Pink | September, 2021 |
| ... | ... |

And I want to consolidate this into a smaller data frame with ranges of enrollment_start and enrollment_end per doctor like this:

| doctor | enrollment_start | enrollment_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dr. Brown | March, 2021 | April, 2021 |
| Dr. Brown | July, 2021 | August, 2021 |
| Dr. Green | April, 2021 | May, 2021 |
| Dr. Black | Jan, 2021 | Jan, 2021 |
| DR. Black | May, 2021 | July, 2021 |
| Dr. Pink | September, 2021 | September, 2021 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Whereby non-continuous enrollment periods are reflected as separate rows.

How might I accomplish this in R, preferably using dplyr / tidyverse syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
            doctor = c("Dr. Brown","Dr. Brown",
                       "Dr. Brown","Dr. Brown","Dr. Green","Dr. Green",
                       "Dr. Black","Dr. Black","Dr. Black","Dr. Black","Dr. Pink"),
    month_enrolled = c("March, 2021","April, 2021",
                       "July, 2021","August, 2021","April, 2021","May, 2021",
                       "Jan, 2021","May, 2021","June, 2021","July, 2021",
                       "September, 2021")
) %>%
  
transmute(doctor, month = dmy(paste(1,month_enrolled))) %>%
group_by(doctor) %>%
mutate(stint = 1 + cumsum(c(0, diff(month) > 31))) %>% # EDIT - shorter
group_by(doctor, stint) %>%
summarize(enrollment_start = min(month),
            enrollment_end = max(month), .groups = "drop")
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  doctor    stint enrollment_start enrollment_end
  <chr>     <dbl> <date>           <date>        
1 Dr. Black     1 2021-01-01       2021-01-01    
2 Dr. Black     2 2021-05-01       2021-07-01    
3 Dr. Brown     1 2021-03-01       2021-04-01    
4 Dr. Brown     2 2021-07-01       2021-08-01    
5 Dr. Green     1 2021-04-01       2021-05-01    
6 Dr. Pink      1 2021-09-01       2021-09-01
```

Comment: This would give me one row per doctor, right? I'd like to see multiple rows per doctor when the enrollment ranges are not continuous. I need to know if there were gaps in enrollment.

Comment: Updated. I looked for months for a doctor that were more than a month from the last one to define a new "stint", and then summarized min/max within each doctor's stint.

Comment: Very nice, thank you for your help today.